# Function to check file exist with specific extention or pattern in C

Tags: c, function

Is there any function to check file(s) exist with specific extension or pattern in a directory(s) in Windows and Linux?

For example, to check for files with bbram extension in nvmdir directory.

```
file_exists(nvmdir .. "\\*.bbram")
```

Comment: POSIX (e.g. Linux or OSX) or Windows? Or something else completely?

Comment: It highly depends on what OS you are using.

Comment: @joachim, I need the functionality for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Ravi What now: check file existence, removal, string concatenation or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat less elegant solution would be to use `popen()` or even lesser elegant `system()` to issue an OS specific "shell" command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want linux/windows compatibility I guess you'll need to do it yourself (look at #ifdef etc to define witch os you're using).

Then you'll need opendir (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), readdir (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) functions.

I let you dig into it.